# Answering "why do you want to leave your current job" without sounding inexperienced due to lack of working in your field

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

I currently work for Company X for 2 years coming up in a few months. I do(or did) computer support. I came in as a technical assistant when the job first opened up. However, the job has over time turned into 90% non-technical work and now I am being told that doing technical work is out of my job description.

My worry is that in my job hunting for another IT Job I'll be asked why I want to leave and being honest about the following:

- Lack of real IT work
- Not getting a promotion of sorts despite having several higher up employees vouch for me from the IT field and hearing I was on the short list but still not getting the job.

I worry that the above could be taken in wrong ways and hinder my chances of getting a better job doing more IT work.

Is there another way to answer this question or the likes there of or should I just be honest and try and explain in ways that won't single me out.

Answer (score 4):

You say: for my current position, my expectations no longer align with my job duties. The job was highly technical at the beginning but has shifted over time and I feel that I am given more and more non-technical responsibilities. While I am okay with that, my real passion lies on the technical side on things. This prompted me to search for a job that better fits my abilities and my expectations.

Answer (score 4):

The standard response in this situation is either

> I am looking for a new challenge.

or

> As I've developed my skills and experience, I find that I've outgrown this role.

or

> I want to increase my experience of {whatever it is the new company do}

Essentially, you're saying (quite truthfully) that you want to do more technical work.  You're not badmouthing your former employer.  You're not doing yourself down.  You're pointing out that you're interested in improving yourself.

Good luck!

Comment: ++ I thought wanting to do more harder work was one of answer you'd make up if it wasn't already true.

Answer (score 2):

You can come up with three reasons to justify leaving the place without saying anything bad about your current work place.

1. I want to utilize more of my skills and work on more challenging issues.
2. I want to stay on top of my industry and I am concern that I hit a stalemate in this position.
3. Work on technologies more relevant to my interests and background.